# website running on Amazon Cloud

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I want to run the website on my local machine . The website is hosted on the amazon cloud and i dont find any document describing to host the website on local machine . Is it possible to download all the files and make the website alive in the local computer ?

Answer (score -1):

Do you want to configure web server or do you want to move the source code to your local machine if it is moving your source code then you can by opening a 21 (FTP port) in the cloud machine pointing to your local and transfer the files.

Comment: i have copied the file and i am new to AWS . I have developed the webste in php i dont know how to configure those files in local host

Comment: This is not very helpful. It's unlikely (and inadvisable anyway) that there is an FTP server running on the AWS instance. Much better to use SFTP using the ssh credentials.

Comment: What should i do on my local machine to run that files smoothly . Visual studio ?